# Updating the state correctly after fetch data from firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to use Firestore Snapchats to get real time changes on a database.  I am using `react-native-cli: 2.0.1` and `react-native: 0.64.1` .

```
export const WelcomeScreen = observer(function WelcomeScreen() {
    const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);
    
    const onResult = (querySnapshot) => {
       const items =  []
       firestore()
       .collection("Test")
       .get()
       .then((querySnapshot) => {
           querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
             const tempData = {key: doc.id, data: doc.data}
              items.push(tempData);
           });
           setListData(items)
        });
      }
      
      const onError = (error) => {
        console.error(error);
      }
      
      firestore().collection('Test').onSnapshot(onResult, onError);

}
```

Every thing is working perfectly, until I use setListData to update the data list. The App does not respond anymore and I get a warning message each time I try to add or delete data from the database

> Please report: Excessive number of pending callbacks: 501. Some pending callbacks that might have leaked by never being called from native code

I am creating a deadlock by setting the state this way?

Comment: is it ok to use `useState` outside of functional component

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you don't want to set up a snapshot listener in the body of your component. This results in a growing number of listeners, because every time you render you add a new listener, but every listener results in rendering again, etc. So set up the listener just once in a useEffect:

```
const [listData, setListData] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
  function onResult(querySnapshot) {
    // ...
  }
  function onError(error) {
    console.log(error);
  }

  const unsubscribe = firestore().collection('Test').onSnapshot(onResult, onError);
  return unsubscribe;
}, []);
```

In addition, your onResult function is going to get called when you get the result, and yet you're having it turn around and immediately doing a `get` to re-request the data it already has. Instead, just use the snapshot you're given:

```
function onResult(querySnapshot) {
  const items = []
  querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
    const tempData = {key: doc.id, data: doc.data()}
    items.push(tempData);
  });
  setListData(items);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Just one question, where is 'unsubscribe' being returned? Where can I use it?

Comment: onSnapshot returns an unsubscribe function which will teardown the snapshot listener. I'm then returning it from the useEffect. When you return a function from a useEffect, this tells react what cleanup logic the effect requires. React will call unsubscribe when the component unmounts (or when the effect runs again, but that won't happen for this effect).